# Android - Bitmap and memory management?

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

How can i manage the memory for the following situation?

```
Bitmap bitmap = myBitmapProvider.getBitmap();
myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Based on my understanding this would cause a memory leak (And yes I am getting out of memory crashes)
// I tried the following code but it crasshed the app because the bitmap is in-use by my ImageView, so what is the correct solution\?

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are either creating a lot of those bitmaps or just one large one. If it is just one large one you should check out this post on downsampling images for displaying on the screen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/317862

If your creating a lot of them maybe check out this article: http://www.senab.co.uk/2011/12/28/image-caching/

Comment: the link to senab.co.uk is "dead" =(

Comment: It is often a good idea to summarise the important points in your answer, rather than just providing a link (because the link may break, the contents of the linked to site may change, etc.).

Comment: @sgarman:  The link is broken. Please provide the answer if you know the content of the link. It will really help. Thanks